# Probability of the intersection of events compared with the union of "not" events

Tags: probability

If the event $\psi_v$ either does or does not occur at any $v \in V$, then which of these statements is accurate?

$$
P\left(\bigcap_{v \in V}\psi_v\right) = 1 - \sum_{v \in V}\left(1 - P\left(\psi_v\right)\right)
$$

$$
P\left(\bigcap_{v \in V}\psi_v\right) \geq 1 - \sum_{v \in V}\left(1 - P\left(\psi_v\right)\right)
$$

I would have thought it was the top one, (which says "$\psi$ at all $v$" has the same probability as `not $\psi$' at any $v$), but someone is claiming I must use the second statement - are they right?

Comment: It might happen that $\psi_v$'s are not disjoint.

Comment: Hint: DeMorgan's Laws and $P(A\cup B) \leq P(A)+P(B)$.

Comment: isn't A or not A the definition of disjoint?

Comment: You can have $\psi_{v_1} \cap \psi_{v_2} \neq \emptyset$. That is why the above inequality has $\le$ in between.

Comment: I understand, but if $\psi_{v_1}$ is the event "not $\psi_{v_2}$" then surely they cannot occur together?

Comment: OK, so A + B + ... + Z is the far term on the rhs, but this does not mean the union of A,B...Z - the probability of the union is potentially smaller than A + B + ... + Z

Comment: More importantly, @VaibhavJena , it is likely that the complements, $\{\psi_v^\complement\}_{v\in V}$ are not disjoint.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I think what you suggested seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathsf P(\bigcap_{v\in V}\psi_v) = 1-\mathsf P(\bigcup_{v\in V}\psi_v^\complement)\geq 1 - \sum_{v\in V} \mathsf P(\psi_v^\complement)$

Because it is likely that the *complements* of the events $\psi_v$ are not disjoint.  The event could not-occur at more than one point in the set $V$.